# How to get MySQL Search Results by Shortest String when grouped?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I am running:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a
GROUP BY a.prefixNumber
ORDER BY LENGTH(a.uniqueName) ASC, a.prefixNumber;
```

Two or more rows of data may contain the same `prefixNumber` in the form of `ABC-123`, however they will have a unique name for each `prefixNumber`. I want the `uniqueName` that has the shortest length, while still being able to group by the `prefixNumber`.

I'm guessing there is something going on when I do the `GROUP BY` clause, but I'm not exactly sure as my SQL skills aren't the highest. I've been searching around and I found the `Length(a.uniqueName)` solution. That does not seem to fix my problem, as I will still get the longest name for a few scenarios.

Soultions?

Comment: Your query is invalid as you have columns, that aren't in the `GROUP BY` and also not parameters to an aggregation function. Older versions of MySQL or loosely configured ones may accept such erroneous queries but the results may be surprising. And it's missing a `FROM` clause. To convey what you want an erroneous query, that doesn't do what you want is pretty useless. Please edit your question and add the `CREATE` statements of the tables involved, sample data as `INSERT` statements for these tables and the desired result that should be produced with the given sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are looking to remove duplicates on `prefixNumber`, by selecting the record that has the shortest `uniqueName`.

I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead of aggregation:

```
SELECT a1.* 
FROM a a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM a a2
    WHERE 
        a2.prefixNumber = a1.prefixNumber 
        AND LENGTH(a2.uniqueName) < LENGTH(a1.uniqueName)
)
ORDER BY a1.prefixNumber
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition uses a correlated subquery to ensure that there is no other record with the same `prefixNumber` and a shortest `uniqueName`.

---

In MYSQL 8.0, you can use window functions, which are usually more efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prefixNumber ORDER BY LENGTH(uniqueName)) rn
    FROM a
) x 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Would you be able to go into a little more detail as to what the `NOT EXISTS` clause is doing? Please and Thank you!

Comment: Another question after your edits, would it matter if there were more than 2 rows that had the same prefix number?

Comment: @MarkHill: nope, it doesn't matter. In that case, only the record that has the shortest `uniqueName` will be selected.